# Yeoman generator for WebPart can't find Github repo #spfx #spfx-webparts #spfx-tooling

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I'm trying to create a new WebPart using the directions [here](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part). When I try to install the yeoman generator @microsoft/sharepoint it attempts to reference a github repository (microsoft/sharepoint) that doens't exist or is private.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you set up dev environment properly?. Refer below link https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment

Comment: In addition to the comments below about setting up the environment, the install of the generator is "npm i -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint" while creating a new webpart using the generator is "yo @microsoft/sharepoint"

Answer (score 1):

Do you make sure below steps are performed.

Download and npm package

Install [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) Long Term Support (LTS) v4.x.x version.

After installing node, make sure you are running V3 of npm by running the following command:

```
npm install -g npm@3
```

Install windows build tools.

```
npm install -g --production windows-build-tools
```

Enter the following command to install Yeoman and gulp:

```
npm install -g yo gulp
```

Enter the following command to install the Yeoman SharePoint generator:

```
npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint
```

If there are any errors in above steps it means your development environment is not setup correctly

[Ref link](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)